# Reference request: simple Lagrange multiplier theorem/min-max theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am looking for a textbook reference for a result that is something like the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $X$, $Y$ and $\Lambda$ be TVSes with $Y,\Lambda$ in strong duality, and denote the associated bilinear map by $b$. Let $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g \colon X \to Y$ and define $\mathcal{L} \colon X \times \Lambda \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = f(x) + b(\lambda, g(x)-y)$. Then,
> $$ \inf_{x \in X}\sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \inf_{x \in X}\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)\,.$$

Happy to make it Hilbert space based.

Comment: Not sure but Ekeland and Temam is worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, had a look! Its the same story as all the books I'm familiar with. Lower semicontinuity/subderivatives etc. I'm hoping for something much more straightforward. The proof of the statement is elementary, but its half a page long, and it feels silly to include it in a paper when someone must have written this down before!